# "TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting" in a Python list

Tags: python, arguments, string-formatting, typeerror

I am writing a recursive function that will print the result of converting a base 10 integer to its equivalent in another base. At line 11 I receive:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here and how should I fix it?

```
list = []

def con2base(integer, base):
    if integer == 0:
        if list == []:
            list.insert(0, 0)
            return 0
        else:
            return 0
    while integer > 0:
        list.insert(0, (integer % base))    <----- This is the offending line
        return con2base(integer / base, base)

print ("Enter number to be converted: ")
integer = raw_input()
print ("Enter base for conversion: ")
base = raw_input()
con2base(integer, base)

print list
```

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input` will always return a string object, and never an actual integer. You need to convert both of them to `int`s first.

```
print ("Enter number to be converted: ")
integer = int(raw_input())
print ("Enter base for conversion: ")
base = int(raw_input())
con2base(integer, base)
```

The reason for the weird error message is that `%` is an operator that also works on strings; specifically, it's the string format operator. It lets you create one string with "placeholder" elements, which you can fill in at runtime with other strings. So when you get the numbers using `raw_input` and then try to use `%`, Python thinks you are trying to do string formatting/substitution.